# Dimming a tintColor on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, ios7

Here is a UITableViewCell that opens a modal ('Add Ingredients'):

[image]

I am setting the label color to match the application's tintColor:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Ingredients...";
cell.textLabel.textColor = [self.view tintColor];
```

How do I dim the text color when a `UIAlertView` or `UIActionSheet` is presented? This behavior is default for buttons and other controls, but not for a cell's text label.

I have found references to tintAdjustmentMode and tintColorDidChange, but do not know how to use either.

Or should I be adding a button to my cell? My previous experience with this approach wasn't optimal - there were side-efffects with responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct. You should just be able to override the tintColorDidChange method in your CustomUITableViewCell.

http://www.qubop.com/ios7.pdf

Comment: I see - so I need to use a custom cell subclass rather than one of the standard cells. I will try this out.