# Images in UITableView cells are not honoring tintColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tintcolor

I have a `UITableView` which is comprised of static cells. In IB I've set each `UITableViewCell`'s style to "Basic" and set an image (see screenshot). The buttons in my nav bar honor the `tintColor` property but the images in the tableview do not. Thus far I've done everything in IB - do I *have* to use code if I want the images to honor the `tintColor` property too?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855080/dimming-a-tintcolor-on-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: So this can't be done in IB? That seems really odd since, IMHO, this is normally what I'd want to happen by default. And since these are static cells I really don't want to have to do everything in code if I don't have to.

Comment: cellImageView dont have tint color property. you have to use custom cell and little code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145953/how-to-tint-an-image-show-a-colour

Comment: If you don't want do anything in code why not change the image original color as you want?

Comment: @dopcn I'd like to be able to change the color easily later. So creating my images with a specific color would be troublesome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every `UIImageView` has the property `tintColor` on iOS7+

Try to set cell's `imageView.image.renderingMode` to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` in storyboard `User Defined Runtime Attributes`

Comment: i am using vector pdfs which are rendered as template. they show up fine with the set tint color everywhere except for on of my custom cells where the images are inside an image view. how do i deal with this?

Comment: I have the same problem with image views contained in a table cell. I usually just use a UIButton instead and just set its interactionEnabled to false. There's virtually no difference except that a button doesn't always hug the exact size of the image specially the very small ones.

Answer (score 9):

What a headache this problem is after so many versions! The only thing that is a sure fire fix, assuming everything is "right" (template image, etc) is subclassing the UIImageView and overriding didMoveToSuperview with this...

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    [self setHighlighted:YES];
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
}
```

It's a hack but it works.

Comment: This hack works well in such case that tint color is applied only after tap the cell. Thanks!

Comment: Same.  In the scenario where the UIImageView was in a UICollectionViewCell and was not being highlighted until after the cell was tapped, adding this to my UIImageView subclass did create the correct effect.  *sigh...*

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_email_white"]
                  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[[cell imageView] setImage:image];
[[cell imageView] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The below setup worked for me well.

In the storyboard, set cell's `contentView` `tintColor` as your desired color and  `UIImagview`'s `tintColor` as `default`.