# Images in UITableView cells are not honoring tintColor: it works only when cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I know that there is another question with the same title, but none of them worked - especially [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25849101) should solve the problem, but it is not. I set in Assets.xcassets, Render as 'Template Image' and tried to use awakeFromNib() or tintColorDidChange() in a subclass of UITableViewCell, even tried to use a white image with transparent background, but nothing works.

Original question: the tint color feature for an UIImageView inside of a UITableViewCell (with xib file) doesn't work. How to solve it? I use Xcode 10.1 and depolyment target is iOS 10 using Swift 4.2

Comment: is it working with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938514/82813

Comment: Oh, yes, I read it before but now I tried it and it works. Swift 4.2: `class TintImageView: UIImageView { override func didMoveToSuperview() { self.isHighlighted = true self.isHighlighted = false super.didMoveToSuperview() } }`